# Ad Hoc should be for development iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, distribution, adhoc

Just I want to send the ipa file to my customer in order to test it, I have searched about my question, but unfortunately I did not find the answers.

When the customer want to install the ipa file through iTunes, should his iOS device be registered as a development device in developer.apple.com or no ?

Note: I have installed the ipa to my device successfully, but I don't know if it is completed because my iPhone is already registered .

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would give TestFlight a try. Very Easy to handle...

https://testflightapp.com

Comment: Looks stunning :) I will check it and go back, appreciated your nice response ... thanks

Comment: OMG .. The most powerful site I have seen ever for iOS testing idea ! Big thanks TompaLompa :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on the provisioning Portal under `Device` you first need to insert the UDID of the (new) device.

Then, below, in the `Provisioning menu` go to the `Distribution tab`.
There, either create a new profile or edit an existing profile. Ensure the device is part of the profile.

After submission of the new/modified profile wait a while. Within a few minutes the download button appears (you will need to refresh the tab).

Download the certificate from Safari and drag&drop it into the Xcode organizer or download it from within Xcode.

Exit Xcode and reopen (helps avoiding strange certificate problems), then Build&Archive

Comment: really !! what about if I have many customers, shall I register each device to my account !!! if yes maybe the 99 devices that apples allow developers to sign them as a development devices will finish ! right ?

Comment: We run most of the ad hoc test on the profiles of our customers as 100 devices are not enough if you have a fair number of clients.